# Source of 3 daily miracles love of occupation, place of living and wife

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, agada-stories-legends

I heard a shiur of Gemara (I might be mistaken with the details):

The world would not be able to exist if not for Hashem causing 3 constant miracles, that man: 1 enjoys his occupation, 2 enjoys his place of living, and 3 enjoys his wife.

Where is the Gemara that says something similar to this?

Comment: enjoys his occupation https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.43b.5

Comment: +1 but note, it’s an isolated *gem.* with no connection to “Hashem causing 3 constant miracles”.

Comment: @Oliver i understand, I lost it, today I found it

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're looking for, or at least the origin of the adage, is the talmud ([Sot. 47a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.47a.4?lang=bi)):

> אמר רבי יוחנן שלשה חינות הן חן מקום על יושביו חן אשה על בעלה חן מקח על מקחו

Trans. from Sefaria:

> **Rabbi Yoḥanan says: There are three graces** that have a similar impact: **The grace of a place upon its inhabitants; the grace of a woman upon her husband**, despite her faults; and **the grace of a purchased** item **upon its buyer**, as one who has bought something views it in a positive light.

Comment: +1 thank you, Seems very similar, (but I remember something about the occupation to)

Comment: @hazoriz I'm doubtful of an original source saying so bec the (likely) statement of RY is also brought in PT ([Yoma 4:1](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/ירושלמי_יומא_דף_כ_א)) with no alternative reading. Unless the shiur was in English and the speaker used the word "occupation" in a different sense, i.e. possession or control, in that case see the statement of R. Avin in PT right before the aforementioned cit.; although they are two separate statements.

Comment: "despite her faults"  Interesting-the place can have bad areas, the item can have factory defects, but only the wife gets a pass on faults that it seems it's assumed she has.

Comment: @Gary That’s Sefaria’s addition. The original text makes no mention of that - just the grace of each of these things, with no tags. In fact, in context, it’s addressing the inhabitants of Yericho whose water was bad and whose women miscarried, yet they still loved their town in spite of its downsides. ויאמרו אנשי העיר אל אלישע הנה נא מושב העיר טוב כאשר אדוני רואה וגו׳ וכי מאחר דמים רעים וארץ משכלת אלא מה טובתה אמר רבי חנין חן מקום על יושביו אמר רבי יוחנן וכו׳

Comment: @DonielF it is stainzalts addition based on Rashi https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Sotah.47a.4.3

Comment: @hazoriz Read the previous Rashi - he makes the same point about the place, and presumably he just didn’t bother saying it again about the grace of an object on its owner.

Comment: @Doniel F - and hazoriz: Thanks, guys!  Those three nonoriginal words make a pretty big difference in the meaning(attitude?) of the quote, to me at least.